# Delete .mov files from app

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

This is how I write video data to file:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"
let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
let name = "\(date).mov"
let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let url = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)
videoData.writeToFile(url.path!, atomically: true)
```

When the app terminates, I want to delete the files I created before.
This is what I am doing now:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    for url in urls {
        if url.absoluteString.containsString(".mov") {
            try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you find the .mov files? What about using `removeItemAtURL:error:` to maybe log an error? Note that you can't do a lot in `applicationWillTerminate:` You have around 5 seconds to do things. Is `applicationWillTerminate:` even called? Do you have background mode?

Comment: What about catch the error to see what it have to say ?

Comment: I have tried to user this method to print all `.mov` files when the app launches. But it didn't printed out anything, indicating this method cannot find the files it had created before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    let documentPath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let url:NSURL = documentPath[0]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let files = fileManager.enumeratorAtPath(url.path!)
    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
         if file.containsString(".mp4") {
            let filepath = url.path! + "/\(file)"
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(filepath)
                print("removeurlsuccess")
            } catch let error{
                print("removeurlfail")

            }
        }

    }        // Override point for customizati
}
```

Comment: What does `cacheURL` and `url` mean? they are used before they are created.

Comment: Sorry, since I don't know too much about files, I can't modify your code by myself. Again, the `urls` is an array, but it should be a url.

Answer (score 0):

I think more simpler will be create new directory, write videos to it. And when you need just delete this directory.